# Cant get GUID from newly created Record

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, workflow

With the line:

```
Guid AlertsId = service.Create(NewAlert);
NewAlert["new_alertguid"] = "Spennende: " + AlertsId.ToString();
```

I am trying to get the newly created GUID.
But nothing happens. I dont get the GUID and the workflow does not fail.
It does not write "Spennende" in the field neither. But I cant see how to find out what I am doing wrong.

What can I do to solve this. Do you guys see anything wrong?

Tried to insert other values in the same field.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;

namespace WordCountWorkflow
{
    public class WordCount : CodeActivity
    {



        [Input("Hvilket felt skal endres")]
        public InArgument<string> FieldToChange { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        [Input("Tekst som skal telles")]
        public InArgument<string> InputText { get; set; }

        [Output("Antall tegn")]
        public OutArgument<int> CountOfWords { get; set; }


        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            this.CountOfWords.Set(
                context,
                this.InputText.Get<string>(context).Split(
                    new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' },
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length);
            //------------------
            ITracingService tracingService = context.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            IWorkflowContext workflowContext = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = context.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(workflowContext.UserId);
            Entity NewAlert = new Entity("new_alerts");
            NewAlert["new_name"] = "Navn på alert";
            NewAlert["new_message"] = "Her er beskjed";
            Guid AlertsId = service.Create(NewAlert);
            NewAlert["new_alertguid"] = "Spennende: " + AlertsId.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change to this:

```
    ITracingService tracingService = context.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
    IWorkflowContext workflowContext = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = context.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(workflowContext.UserId);
    Entity NewAlert = new Entity("new_alerts");
    Guid AlertsId = service.Create(NewAlert);
    NewAlert["new_name"] = "Navn på alert";
    NewAlert["new_message"] = "Her er beskjed " + AlertsId.ToString();
    NewAlert["new_shortmessage"] = "Spennende: " + AlertsId.ToString();
```

But then everything stopped. And none of the fields where filled out.

Comment: What do you get in `AlertsId` variable?

Comment: It is blank. And actually it does not write "Spennende" in the field neither.
But it does not fail, so I do not get any error to look at.

Comment: Then you need to look in the service code to see what's happening there.

Comment: Where do I find that? 
I am totally new to developing workflows. This is my first.

Comment: I presume it has something to do with 
Guid AlertsId = service.Create(NewAlert);

Comment: As it stands, your workflow does exactly what you instruct it to do: It creates a new `new_alerts` entity record, then modifies some properties but never saves these changes. If you want to see these changes persisted, you need to `service.Update(NewAlert);` as your last instruction.

Comment: So I tried to add:
NewAlert["new_shortmessage"] = "Spennende: " + AlertsId.ToString();
service.Update(NewAlert);

But it did not work

Comment: Is there any other way of getting the GUID of the newly created Record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code with you creating guid for a record

```
Entity NewAlert = new Entity("new_alerts");
NewAlert.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
NewAlert["new_name"] = "Navn på alert";
NewAlert["new_message"] = "Her er beskjed";            
NewAlert["new_alertguid"] = "Spennende: " + NewAlert.Id.ToString();
Guid AlertsId = service.Create(NewAlert);
```

OR you can create new Object and then update it.

```
Entity NewAlert = new Entity("new_alerts");
NewAlert["new_name"] = "Navn på alert";
NewAlert["new_message"] = "Her er beskjed";
Guid AlertsId = service.Create(NewAlert);        
Entity CompleteNewAlert = new Entity("new_alerts",AlertsId );
CompleteNewAlert ["new_alertguid"] = "Spennende: " + AlertsId.ToString();
service.Update(CompleteNewAlert );
```

Comment: I tried the one on top, but then I god only: "Spennende: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". No actually GUID. But we are closer:-)

Comment: Try the bottom one it shall be easier for you

Comment: I will try it when I am at my computer again. But why did not the one on top work?

Comment: Got the first one to work too. Apparently something I did wrong last time.